How std::weak_ptr::lock() is implemented to garantee both shared_ptr and weak_ptr can be used from threads without further synchronization
How std::weak_ptr::lock() is implemented to garantee both shared_ptr and weak_ptr can be used from threads without further synchronization(see the example code).
As per the cppreference, which says that

std::weak_ptr<T>::lock Effectively returns expired() ? shared_ptr() : shared_ptr(*this), executed atomically.

Here is the example code.
#include<memory>
#include<thread>

std::shared_ptr<int> g_s = std::make_shared<int>(1);
std::weak_ptr<int> w_p{g_s};

void f1(std::weak_ptr<int>& wp)
{
    std::shared_ptr<int>l_s1 = wp.lock(); // read g_s
}

void f2()
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> l_s2 = std::make_shared<int>(3);
    std::thread th(f1, std::ref(w_p));
    th.detach();
    g_s = l_s2; // write g_s
}

int main()
{
    std::thread(f2).join();
}

And I found some related code in the headers of C++(/usr/include/c++/7/bits/shared_ptr.h and
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/shared_ptr_base.h on my local system, similar code could be seen at here)
      __shared_ptr<_Tp, _Lp>
      weak_ptr::lock() const noexcept
      { return __shared_ptr<element_type, _Lp>(*this, std::nothrow); }
      
      
      
      shared_ptr<_Tp>
      weak_ptr::lock() const noexcept
      { return shared_ptr<_Tp>(*this, std::nothrow); }
      
      /**
       *  @brief  Constructs a %shared_ptr that shares ownership with @a __r
       *          and stores a copy of the pointer stored in @a __r.
       *  @param  __r  A weak_ptr.
       *  @post   use_count() == __r.use_count()
       *  @throw  bad_weak_ptr when __r.expired(),
       *          in which case the constructor has no effect.
       */
      template<typename _Yp, typename = _Constructible<const weak_ptr<_Yp>&>>
    explicit shared_ptr(const weak_ptr<_Yp>& __r)
    : __shared_ptr<_Tp>(__r) { }
    
    
    template<typename _Yp, typename = _Compatible<_Yp>>
    explicit __shared_ptr(const __weak_ptr<_Yp, _Lp>& __r)
    : _M_refcount(__r._M_refcount) // may throw
    {
      // It is now safe to copy __r._M_ptr, as
      // _M_refcount(__r._M_refcount) did not throw.
      _M_ptr = __r._M_ptr;
    }


    template<typename _Yp,
           typename = _Constructible<const shared_ptr<_Yp>&>>
    weak_ptr::weak_ptr(const shared_ptr<_Yp>& __r) noexcept
    : __weak_ptr<_Tp>(__r) { }
    
      // The "obvious" converting constructor implementation:
      //
      //  template<typename _Tp1>
      //    __weak_ptr(const __weak_ptr<_Tp1, _Lp>& __r)
      //    : _M_ptr(__r._M_ptr), _M_refcount(__r._M_refcount) // never throws
      //    { }
      //
      // has a serious problem.
      //
      //  __r._M_ptr may already have been invalidated. The _M_ptr(__r._M_ptr)
      //  conversion may require access to *__r._M_ptr (virtual inheritance).
      //
      // It is not possible to avoid spurious access violations since
      // in multithreaded programs __r._M_ptr may be invalidated at any point.
      template<typename _Yp, typename = _Compatible<_Yp>>
    __weak_ptr(const __weak_ptr<_Yp, _Lp>& __r) noexcept
    : _M_refcount(__r._M_refcount)
        { _M_ptr = __r.lock().get(); }

      template<typename _Yp, typename = _Compatible<_Yp>>
    __weak_ptr(const __shared_ptr<_Yp, _Lp>& __r) noexcept
    : _M_ptr(__r._M_ptr), _M_refcount(__r._M_refcount)
    { }
    
    
    explicit
    shared_ptr::shared_ptr(_Yp* __p) : __shared_ptr<_Tp>(__p) { }
    
    __shared_ptr(_Yp* __p)
    : _M_ptr(__p), _M_refcount(__p, typename is_array<_Tp>::type())
    {
      static_assert( !is_void<_Yp>::value, "incomplete type" );
      static_assert( sizeof(_Yp) > 0, "incomplete type" );
      _M_enable_shared_from_this_with(__p);
    }


the _M_refcount constructor presumably does an atomic increment of the reference count

As you have discovered in the standard library code,

std::weak_ptr::lock() constructs a corresponding std::shared_ptr.
The std::shared_ptr(std::weak_ptr, std::nothrow) constructor constructs a __shared_count from a __weak_count.
That constructor ends up calling _Sp_counted_base::_M_add_ref_lock_nothrow():

template<>
inline bool
_Sp_counted_base<_S_atomic>::_M_add_ref_lock_nothrow() noexcept
{
    // Perform lock-free add-if-not-zero operation.
    _Atomic_word __count = _M_get_use_count();
    do
    {
        if (__count == 0)
            return false;
        // Replace the current counter value with the old value + 1, as
        // long as it's not changed meanwhile.
    }
    while (!__atomic_compare_exchange_n(&_M_use_count, &__count, __count + 1,
                    true, __ATOMIC_ACQ_REL,
                    __ATOMIC_RELAXED));
    return true;
}

This function atomically does:
if (_M_use_count == 0)
    return false;
++_M_use_count;
return true;

Subsequently, if false is returned, a null shared_ptr is returned, and a shared_ptr owning the same resource as the weak_ptr otherwise.
This corresponds to expired() ? shared_ptr() : shared_ptr(*this).
It also wouldn't be quite accurate to say that this is happening "without further synchronization".
This method may be lock-free, but it still requires atomic operations and a CAS-and-retry loop, which are a form of synchronization.
If a lot of threads are trying to lock a std::weak_ptr for the same resource at the same time (see What is thread contention?), this may result in the __atomic_compare_exchange_n failing repeatedly.
